# Combine two random words in array then join words into one word

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, random

I have a list of words in an array and I am trying to output the words to make one word,

Example would be the words "one", "two", "three", "four" in my Array and I would

want the output possibly to be:

onethree or fourtwo, or onefour, etc...

Any help would be awesome! This is what I have so far but can get it to perform correctly

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var randomtxt = [
"ONE","TWO","THREE",
    "FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN"
];

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomtxt.length); 
var randomElement = randomtxt[randomIndex];
$('#text-content').text(randomElement + randomtxt.join(", "));

});
```

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.. have a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/dFJ5E/

Comment: Could you elaborate on the expected output?

Comment: Its taking a  random string in the array and merging into one word. So the output could be: "twothree" "onefour" "sixone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you should use something like this:

```
var words = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" ];
$( "#text-content" ).text( createNewWord( words ) );

function getRandomWord( wordsArray ) {
    var index = Math.floor( Math.random() * wordsArray.length );
    return wordsArray[index];
}

function createNewWord( wordsArray ) {

    var newWordPart1 = getRandomWord( wordsArray );
    var newWordPart2 = getRandomWord( wordsArray );

    // this will prevent new words like oneone twotwo, etc.
    // if you want the repeated words, just remove this while entirely
    while ( newWordPart2 == newWordPart1 ) {
        newWordPart2 = getRandomWord( wordsArray );
    }

    return newWordPart1 + newWordPart2;

}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/UwXHT/